# Найти совпадение по всем столбцам

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

У мня есть таблица.

```
 id |  name  |       email     |     phone    |
-----------------------------------------------
  1 |  Ваня  | vanya@gmail.com | +79509509509 |
  2 |  Коля  | kolia@gmail.com | +79519519510 |
  3 |  Катя  | katia@gmail.com | +79529529520 |
```

Мне приходят данные, например такие:

```
{
    name: 'Ваня',
    email: 'vanya@gmail.com',
    phone: '+79509509509'
}
```

В ответ я хочу получить `true`, потому что эти данные совпадают с записью номер 1.

```
{
    name: 'Коля',
    email: 'kolia@gmail.com',
    phone: '+79529529520'
}
```

В ответ я хочу получить `false`, потому что эти данные не совпадают не с одной записью.

Как можно реализовать такой запрос к базе данный?

Comment: В запросе следует в секции WHERE использовать условия по равенству всех полей заданным значениям. `WHERE field1=value1 AND field2= value2 AND ...`. И полученный результат преобразовать в ответ нужного типа.

Comment: какой SQL сервер?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select count(*) as count from table where name=$1 and email=$2 and phone=$3
```

Далее просто проверяете,  `count > 0`. И нужны индексы на эти поля.

Comment: @Akina Если автор не указал ничего по поводу дубликатов, значит это не важно. Поправил ответ анивей. (Вы коммент на 20 сек раньше отправили, но я не стал удалять ответ)

Comment: После изменения `=1` на `>0` претензии отпали.